# Python multiprocessing with List input from CSV

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

Trying multiprocessing with a list input from a CSV

I have a function that takes a list as input.
I'm currently passing the input from a CSV file, where each row is a List.
However, instead of running the function row by row from the CSV, I would like it to multiprocess x rows (say 10) from the CSV and run the function 10 times at once.
I've seen Multiprocessing examples where a single variable is being passed to the function.
However, I'm having trouble trying to multiprocess multiple lists from a CSV.

```
import csv

InputFile = "SampleCSV.csv"


def My_Function(row):
    print(row)
    # Do domething else


if __name__ == '__main__':
    with open(InputFile, 'r') as csvFile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvFile)
        next(reader)  # to skip the header row
        for row in reader:
            a = row
            My_Function(row)

csvFile.close()
```

Comment: clarify your phrase *run the function 10 times at once* - should it be called 10 times in each process?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest
That is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### `multiprocessing` module

You need to have a multiprocessing pool that is as large as your number of cpus.

Since `csv.reader` don't support (as far as I can tell) iteration by more than one row, you'd need to implement some kind of a buffer to accumulate `cpu_count` number of rows and when it's ready, distribute the load to multiple CPUs at once:

```py
import csv
import multiprocessing
import os

cpu_count = os.cpu_count()

def func(row):
    print(row)

with open('test.csv', newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    with multiprocessing.Pool(cpu_count) as p:
        buffer = []
        for row_num, row in enumerate(reader):
            if row_num == 0:
                continue
            buffer.append(row)
            # if read enough rows -> do work
            if row_num % cpu_count == 0:
                p.map(func, buffer)
                # don't forget to clear the buffer
                buffer = []
        else:
            # process leftover rows
            p.map(func, buffer)
```

Comment: Thank you.
I just had to add <<"if __name__ == '__main__':">> and it worked perfectly.